Remix : how to return 404 response when custom exception class is thrown?
The database access layer of my Remix application throws a custom NoRecordFound error when no records are found in database lookups. Example (in app/routes/item.$id.jsx):
import { json } from "@remix-run/node"
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react"
import { getItem } from "../data-access-layer"

export const loader = async ({ params }) => {
  const item = await getItem(params.id) // throws NoRecordFound if no item matches `params.id`
  return json({ item })
}

export default function Item() {
  const { item } = useLoaderData()

  return (
    <div id="item">
      <h1>{item.title}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

How can I configure Remix so that it automatically renders a 404 Not Found response with the correct 404 HTTP status code when the custom NoRecordFound is thrown?
I know I could catch these NoRecordFound errors and throw Response errors with {status: 404} instead, but I would like to avoid having to do that in every loader function.
Reading Remix Error Handling documentation I was able to catch the custom NoRecordFound error in an ErrorBoundary function of my app's root.tsx, and render specific HTML for this error. Example:
export function ErrorBoundary() {
  const error = useRouteError()
  if (error instanceof NoRecordFound) {
    return <html>404 Not Found</html>
  }
  else {
    return <html>An error occurred</html>
  }
}

However this does not change the HTTP status code returned (it remains 500 for all errors). How can I change this to 404 for instances of NoRecordFound?
Thanks

Can't you just return a Response with {status: 404} inside ErrorBoundary?

Wow I didn't realize you can actually return a Response object from ErrorBoundary... I'm still definitely a noob with Remix. Thank you!

As commented by gre_gor, I can actually just return a Response with {status: 404} inside ErrorBoundary.
